# Cant use LIKE to extract data from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have been battling with this code for some time and could do with some advice.  I have created a mysql database of computer games and a simple search box and button within a form.  If I type in any key word regarding the name of the game or its description, php should echo the results in a drop down (since there might be more than one 'hit').  At present, I'm just showing the results at the bottom of the page.  My query happily runs the else statement and shows me all the games on offer, but I get no results when I type in the search criteria and no error messages. print_r($q) also draws a blank. What's going wrong?
NB. I'm not too worried about code injection at this point - 1 baby step at a time! Many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head></head>

<?php
//Connect to the Database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "Secret";
$dbname = "gaming";

//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

// Show error if connection fails
if (!$conn){ 
    die("Connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $sql="SELECT* FROM gamestbl WHERE game_name LIKE '%.$search.%' OR game_description LIKE '%.$search.%'";
    $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
else{
    $sql="SELECT* FROM gamestbl";
    $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
?>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Search</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="search" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Find " /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Game ID</td>
        <td>Game Name</td>
        <td>Game Description</td>
        <td>Game Genre</td>
        <td>Game Price</td>
    </tr>

<?php
print_r($q);
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_genre'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_description'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_price'];?></td>
</tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
<?php
// get rid of data in cache and close
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Try to do a `$q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());` and see it has some error. On the other hand, you should escape all string you use in queries to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: It seems ``$search`` is empty, that's why its showing all your results (``LIKE "%%"``)

Comment: You dont need use concatenate for the `LIKE` statement inside a string. In your example just replace `%.$search.%` for `%{$search}%` and PHP indentify the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$sql="SELECT* FROM gamestbl WHERE game_name LIKE '%.$search.%' OR game_description LIKE '%.$search.%'";
```

For

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search); // Prevent from injection
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM gamestbl WHERE concat(game_name, game_description) LIKE '%s'", '%' . $search . '%');
```

sprintf is the better way to add variable in a string and concat will make your sql shorter by avoiding "OR".

Comment: It looks like you're missing a quote. It would be nice to explain how you've corrected the problem. It would also be good to escape the variables passed to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `'%.$search.%'` you have to use `'%$search%'` (notice skipped dots). Or even better (in my opinion) `'%".$search."%'`.

Currently you are passing dots in your query so instead of searching for `example` you are asking database for rows with `.example.` in name or description.

Comment: Thank you - this really helped me to understand what was going wrong!